# Kafka KStream OutOfOrderSequenceException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Our application intermittently encounters OutOfOrderSequenceException in our streams code. Which causes stream thread to stop.

Implementation is simple, 2 KStreams join and output to another topic.

When searching for a solution to this OutOfOrderSequenceException
I have found below documentation on Confluent

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#out-of-order-handling

But could not find what settings, config or trade-offs are being referred here ?
How to manually do bookkeeping ?

> If users want to handle such out-of-order data, generally they need to
>   allow their applications to wait for longer time while bookkeeping
>   their states during the wait time, i.e. making trade-off decisions
>   between latency, cost, and correctness. ***In Kafka Streams, users can
>   configure their window operators for windowed aggregations to achieve
>   such trade-offs (details can be found in the Developer Guide)***.

Comment: That section is referring to windowing, I believe. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing Out of order events can be handled by maintaining a open-window for the duration that you might expect events to be "late".

Comment: The `OutOfOrderSequenceException` (even if it has a similar name) is not related to "out-of-order data" as discussed on the docs. It's an internal error.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDocs of `OutOfOrderSequenceException`:

> This exception indicates that the broker received an unexpected sequence number from the producer, which means that data may have been lost. If the producer is configured for idempotence only (i.e. if `enable.idempotence` is set and no `transactional.id` is configured), it is possible to continue sending with the same producer instance, but doing so risks reordering of sent records. For transactional producers, this is a fatal error and you should close the producer.

Sequence numbers are internally assigned numbers to each message that is written into a topic.

Because it is an internal error, it's hard to tell what the root cause could be though.

Answer (score 0):

Updates : 
After updating Kafka Brokers and KStream version, issue seems to have subsided.

Also, as per the recommendation, 
https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#recommended-configuration-parameters-for-resiliency

I have updated acks to all. replication factor was already 3.